# custom build with pointerEvent

Tags: openlayers-3

I can not find where to export "pointerEvent" for my custom build. I am checking the "shiftKey" status of the pointerEvent in two places.

1. on a singleclick event:

   evt.pointerEvent.shiftKey
2. on a boxend event:

   evt.mapBrowserEvent.pointerEvent.shiftKey

I can't seem to figure out what I need in my build config.json file. I've tried various combinations of "ol.interaction.*" and "ol.events.*" without sucess. I've grep'd the source for occurrences of "pointerEvent" and "mapBrowserEvent.pointerEvent" and tried to reference those in my exports but I'm pretty much guessing at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Some tests:

**custom-build.json** and [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/peatownz/) with this [custom build](http://data.mapeando.net/tmp/ol-custom.js) (86KB).

```
{
  "exports": [
    "ol.Map",
    "ol.Map#on",
    "ol.Map#addInteraction",
    "ol.layer.Tile",
    "ol.source.OSM",
    "ol.interaction.DragBox",
    "ol.interaction.DragBox#on",
    "ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly",
    "ol.View"
  ],
  "compile": {
    "externs": [
      "externs/closure-compiler.js",
      "externs/oli.js",
      "externs/olx.js",
      "externs/proj4js.js"
    ],
    "define": [
      "ol.ENABLE_DOM=false",
      "ol.ENABLE_WEBGL=false",
      "ol.ENABLE_PROJ4JS=false",
      "ol.ENABLE_VECTOR=false",
      "goog.array.ASSUME_NATIVE_FUNCTIONS=true",
      "goog.DEBUG=false"
    ],
    "extra_annotation_name": [
      "api", "observable"
    ],
    "compilation_level": "ADVANCED",
    "manage_closure_dependencies": true
  }
}
```

---

<s>There's nothing special</s> you should put in you `config.json`.

Add to your exports array:

```
  "exports": [
    ...
    "ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly"
  ]
```

Try this after build:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt){
  console.info(ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(evt));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but with my custom build your example produces: TypeError: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly is not a function

Comment: thanks but I already had that. Tried various things and find that I get the above errors with non-debug builds but not with debug builds. So my problem doesn't seem to be in the "exports" section.

Comment: My problem seems to be the "compilation_level": "ADVANCED" directive. Without it no errors, huge file size.

Comment: @RichardGreenwood Your problem has nothing to do with `compilation_level`. The problem is that `singleclick` is a complete different event than `boxend`. `singleclick` is already a browser event while `boxend` is an OL event that has browser event inside of it.

Comment: I understand the difference between a singleClick and a boxend, sorry if that wasn't clear in my self-answer. The difference between my not working code and the working code that you provided is that I was checking a property of an object (which works with a debug build) whereas your code uses the  `ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly()` function to test the shiftKey state. I was too stuck on my custom build to see that distinction at first.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a great answer because I don't understand the "why", but for the record - I'm checking the shiftKey status after a singleClick event. With a debug build of ol3 the following code works:

```
myVar = evt.pointerEvent.shiftKey; // only works with a debug build
```

But fails with a non-debug ol3 build. The version below works with non-debug builds:

```
myVar = ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(evt);
```

to check the shiftKey status after a boxend event add the mapBrowserEvent property of the event object:

```
myVar = ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(evt.mapBrowserEvent);
```

When I say a "non-debug" ol3 build above I'm referring to "compilation_level" directive being set to "ADVANCED".